# Is there a way to dynamically stream data from Azue Batch task while the task is running (before it completes)

Tags: azure, azure-batch, azure-data-explorer

I am running an Azure Batch HPC, that spits out CSV file as an out put of a computation (a task run). ***I would like to stream this data to a client app in real time, while the computation is still running***. Is there a way to achieve this? Any example I can use as a model, please?

Answer (score 0):

Without standing up your own long lived process on the node solely for streaming files, the best solution is likely to use one of the [GetFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/file/getfromtask) API's and periodically call it. Depending on how often your application writes data and how in sync you'd want it to be there could also be some optimizations use the [GetFileProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/file/getpropertiesfromtask) API to get the last write time of the file.

Answer (score 0):

brklein's answer is spot on. Here's an [example in Python](https://github.com/Azure/batch-shipyard/blob/d6da749f9cd678037bd520bc074e40066ea35b56/convoy/batch.py#L3243) of a function that while waiting for a task to complete, streams the file out. There are some subtleties that need to be accounted for which are captured in the example code.

Another method is to stream the file into an Azure storage append blob as part of your program which may have nice properties such as persistence independent of the compute node lifetime.

Disclaimer: I'm a contributor for the referenced code.